# Unwanted syntax highlighting in vim

Tags: ubuntu, vim

So im using VIM version 7.4.1689 on a remote Ubuntu system that I ssh'ed into

Recently I have been running into the issue where when I open
up vim to edit any file all of the syntax would well for better terms 
be highlighted. And if I would create a new line that line would also become highlighted in grey. Here's an image of it as well as whats in my vimrc.

[Pic of my vimrc and an example of the grey highlightign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alu1H.png)

I don't get this error when using the default color scheme but when I switch to monokai or solarized it comes up.

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: fyi https://superuser.com/questions/678905/vim-colorscheme-weirdness-for-background-not-non-text-area

Comment: @Kent thanks for the link. I didnt know what the actual issue was but if it is an issue with TMUX I will try out those answers.

Comment: The answers on the link did not really work but I did find a better explanation Ill put it right here. https://sunaku.github.io/vim-256color-bce.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a TMUX issue where the colors from the colorscheme would blend in.
The solution is better explained here https://sunaku.github.io/vim-256color-bce.html

Answer (score 0):

You should set `TERM` in the terminal to 256 colors.

Comment: I currently have it set at t_Co=256 still the same error

Comment: I meant the environment variable `TERM` set in the terminal, that you use. It should be depending on your terminal something like `xterm-256color`.